# Why is unattended-upgrades not sending emails?

Tags: debian, raspbian

I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite. I've configured unattended upgrades as [detailed here](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades), but I don't seem to be getting any emails.

Updates were installed this morning:

```
2016-04-03 06:52:55,942 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2016-04-03 06:52:55,945 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2016-04-03 06:52:55,945 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Raspbian,n=jessie']
2016-04-03 06:54:47,863 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: apt apt-utils gnupg gpgv initramfs-tools libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libhogweed2 libnettle4 libpcre3 libsystemd0 libudev1 locales multiarch-support systemd systemd-sysv tzdata udev
2016-04-03 06:54:47,874 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg_2016-04-03_06:54:47.868197.log'
2016-04-03 06:58:01,365 INFO All upgrades installed
```

I have the required packages installed:

```
unattended-upgrades/stable,now 0.81+rpi1 all [installed]
apt-listchanges/stable,now 2.85.13+nmu1 all [installed]
bsd-mailx/stable,now 8.1.2-0.20141216cvs-2 armhf [installed]
```

`mailx` works fine for sending email (I've set up postfix and all local mail gets passed on to a real mail account; there's nothing in the mail logs from this morning, except the test email I just sent).

Mail is turned on:

```
# /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";
```

Not sure how to debug further :(

Answer (score 3):

Don't I feel a fool...

```
danny@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades | grep Mail
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";
// is to always send a mail if Unattended-Upgrade::Mail is set
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";
```

Email only on errors... that's not the default! I wondered how this happened; then checked what I had in my Pi setup script...

```
sudo sed -i 's/^\/\/Unattended-Upgrade::Mail/Unattended-Upgrade::Mail/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

This line was designed to uncomment the line to send mail, not the only to only send mail on errors. Whoops!

Comment: root is also normally a local mail account. often postfix can be overkill for a small server/VM, and it is yet another daemon running, have a look at ssmtp wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP. Depending on what the servers/VM do, often unattended upgrades might not be the best of the ideas. In the past I traced a source of instability to my "rapsberry" like device to unattended upgrades, though I think the problem is already solved. I also normally have a script/routine that does all the upgrades I need via Ansible, and I only invoke it when I am around to peruse the report.

Comment: I spent several days trying various MTAs, inc ssmtp and postfix was the first one I was able to make do what I needed ([details here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/4c10t3/whats_the_simplest_way_to_forward_mail_for_local/). Overkill it may be, but it was only a few lines once I cracked it, and it's working :)

Comment: This is just a Pi running a few things for me and the kids. I figured it was best to let it keep itself up-to-date than not. If stuff breaks, there's no big deal; but I think that's a smaller risk than an internet-exposed device being unpatched :)